# Typecast double to string - concatenate double to string

Tags: c, casting, double, concatenation

I am using gtk in my c application and wants to display a double as a label in the window.

```
 double d = 1000.50

 label = gtk_label_new (d);
```

I got a compilation error because the function takes a characterstring as an argument.

I am used to java where its easy to concatenate a primitive with a string. Its also easy to typecast a double to string. I have googled about a solution but I can only find examples in c++.

So - how do one typecast a double to string OR concatenate a double with a string?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Use sprintf or snprintf to produce a string. With GLib you can also use the built-in glib version: http://www.gtk.org/api/2.6/glib/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strdup-printf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`snprintf` can be used to do this. You can call `snprintf` with a NULL pointer to evaluate the size it will need for the buffer, so you can allocate enough that the resulting string will fit.

```
double d = 1000.50
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%f", d);
char *str = malloc(len+1);
snprintf(str, len, "%f", d);
label = gtk_label_new (str);
```

Comment: it works thanks!!!! can accept in 4 minutes :-) ... but I guess I should free *str when I am done?

Comment: I'm not sure if gtk will do the free, or how it expects the pointer. If the pointer is copied to internal memory you must free it. Anyway, you should refer to gtk documentation for that to be sure.